# How to fold results from a few async calls

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, fold, flatmap

I want to get the results of my asynchronous function and use them in the *fold* function. Here's my function that didn't work:

```
private fun sendOrderStatus(list: List<OrderStatusEntity>) : Single<Boolean> {
    return Single.just(
        list.fold(true) { initial, item ->
            if (!item.isTerminal()) {

                val info = OrderStateParameters(
                    lon = item.orderStatusLon!!,
                    lat = item.orderStatusLat!!,
                    datetime = item.orderStatusDate!!
                )

                val state = OrderState(item.orderId, item.toSend(), info)

                return tasksUseCase.sendOrderStatusForWorker(state)
                    .doOnSuccess { markSent(item) } // side calling
                    .flatMap {
                        return@flatMap initial && it.isSuccess // that result should be used in *fold*-function
                    }
            } else // stub result
                    true
        }
    )
}
```

So, I intend to return a Single  that will contain the aggregated result of all tasksUseCase.sendOrderStatusForWorker(state) calls.

Thank for any helps!

Comment: I'm not familiar with RxJava, but it seems to me that you should first map this list into a list/stream of singles, then flat map it into a stream of booleans and then fold it.

Comment: Firstly you need to call your asynchronous function and transform her result with rx function .reduce.